# g++: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Tags: compilation, g++, makefile

I am trying to compile a library file using other library files. I am using the following line in my makefile to create gameobject.o:

```
lib/gameobject.o: src/gameobject.cpp src/vector.hpp lib/objectevent.o lib/sprite.o
g++ $^ -c -o $@ $(SFML_FLAGS)
```

All the dependencies comile correctly, but I get the following error when it tries to compile gameobject.o:

```
g++: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

I'm still a bit new to using make/separating compilation, so I'm not quite sure what I should do. Do I just have to compile it without setting an output? Do I have to compile gameobject.o without using any of my other .o files? If that's true, wouldn't compile times get pretty big for large objects if you can't compile libraries with other libraries? Or am I just reading this error completely wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not building a library file here.  A `.o` file is an object file.  Typically there is one object file per source file.  When you use the compiler's `-c` option, it takes a single source file and compiles it into a single object file.  You cannot add other object files into an existing object file, so adding both `.o` and `.cpp` files into the same compiler line with `-c` is not going to work.

If you want to create a library, that would be something like `libfoo.a` (the "a" here stands for "archive").  If you want to create an executable you can do that as well.

You need to be more clear about exactly what result you want before we can describe how to get it.

Comment: I am new to `qt` Where does one change these compiler options ?

Comment: As far as I can see this question has nothing to do with qt.  If you have a question (and you can't find the answer by searching) please ask a new question with full details and appropriate tags to draw the attention of people who might know how to help.

Comment: I should have written `g++` in stead of `qt` then ?

Comment: I have no idea, because I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was having the same problem as the original OP and could not figure out how to use the answer. My problem got solved now by removing the `*` in the pro file and naming each file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I combined some projects of a solution to a single one. I find out there was tow .cpp files with same names and after I did rename one of them It solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can create only one object .o file from one source file.
If you are using makefile to build the project. Make sure you are doing ***$< instead of $^***

```
# Correct one
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


# InCorrect one
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```