# Dynamic library with multiple object files, fails during loading

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

Similar to this post: [Compile multiple C source fles into a unique object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182176/compile-multiple-c-source-fles-into-a-unique-object-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I have to compile multiple C files into a single dynamic shared library.
Here is what I have in my Makefile:

```
_OBJS = file1.o file2.o

CFLAGS += -Wall -I../include 

SHARED_LIB =libdynamic.so

.PHONY: all
all:  (SHARED_LIB)

$(SHARED_LIB): 
        $(CC) -fPIC -c file1.c file2.c $(CFLAGS) 
        $(CC) -shared -o $(SHARED_LIB) -L$/lib -ldl $(_OBJS)
```

However the generated shared library doesn't have the functions belonging to file2.c. How can I get it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating the object files (*.o).

Try:

```
$(SHARED_LIB):
    $(CC) -fPIC -c file1.c -o file1.o $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) -fPIC -c file2.c -o file2.o $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $(SHARED_LIB) -L$/lib -ldl $(_OBJS)
```

Also, you are missing a '$' after the `all:` target.

Comment: Well, you have to add the separator.  :P  Makefiles are very picky - the lines after `$(SHARED_LIB):` MUST have a hard tab as the first character (cannot use spaces).

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the follwoing error when I followed your step:arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Comment: Thanks for the Makefile tip. Yes, I added the tab. Was too quick to report error ;)

Comment: Based on what you are trying to do and the error you are getting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177790/g-fatal-error-cannot-specify-o-with-c-s-or-e-with-multiple-files/16177962.  Maybe this will help you see what you are missing.