# How to use a makefile with Gtk

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gtk, client-server

My code is supposed to be divided into client, server, and header files. This is the makefile when it's all in one file -

```
# change application name here (executable output name)
TARGET=BugTrack

# compiler
CC=gcc
# debug
DEBUG=-g
# optimisation
OPT=-O0
# warnings
WARN=-Wall

PTHREAD=-pthread

CCFLAGS=$(DEBUG) $(OPT) $(WARN) $(PTHREAD) -pipe

GTKLIB=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

# linker
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=$(PTHREAD) $(GTKLIB) -export-dynamic

OBJS= client.o 

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

client.o: client.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) client.c  $(GTKLIB) -o client.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

And this works. But changing the last part to this -

```
OBJS= client.o server.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

client.o: client.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) client.c header.h $(GTKLIB) -o client.o

server.o: server.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) server.c header.h $(GTKLIB) -o server.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

Gives me an error that says `fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files`.
How do I fix it?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177790/g-fatal-error-cannot-specify-o-with-c-s-or-e-with-multiple-files

Comment: You only want to compile 1 source file per rule but you specify multiple files. You are feeding `server.c` and `header.h` into the compiler. Headers are no compilation units on their own. They are compiled implicitely when you compile a source file that includes header. Don't add them to the command line for your compiler. Instead you should add the header to the line above defining the depenendy of the .o file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to put the header files into your compile lines, so just do:

```
OBJS= client.o server.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

client.o: client.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) client.c $(GTKLIB) -o client.o

server.o: server.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) server.c $(GTKLIB) -o server.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

If you need to add header include paths then you can add `-I<path>`